# How to set the text view using the data model in hash map

Tags: android, hashmap

I want to set  the input value using edit text and get the values from that model and have to set the text in `TextView`. I have tried the following method, but it is not working:

**Main Activity**

```
Mode setvalue = new Mode();
Mode getvalue = new Mode();

setvalue.set("jeeva",value1.getText().toString());
calculate.setText(getvalue.get("jeeva"));
```

**Model class**

```
public class Mode {

    private HashMap<String, Object> data;

    public Mode() {
        this.data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    public Object get(String key) {
        return this.data.get(key);
    }

    public void set(String key, Object value) {
        this.data.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error u r getting ?

Comment: You keep making the same kind of questions like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742769/how-to-use-the-hashmap-in-datamodel) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43753983/how-to-set-and-get-using-model-in-hashmap) but you never seem to respond after to give more clarification

Comment: How about `calculate.setText(setvalue.get("jeeva"));`

Comment: you need to type cast your object to string

Comment: This is so stupid, first of all using hashmap in android that too in such a worst way possible. Then initializing object1 and getting value from object2. Please focus on JAVA basics.

Comment: Pls look at what he is post.. in that he is setting the value in one instance and getting the value from other instance.which is null.

Comment: I have post the answer what he is looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try like this**

```
Mode mode = new Mode();

mode.set("jeeva", value1.getText().toString());
String value = (String) mode.get("jeeva");
calculate.setText(value);
```

Hope its help!